# How to parse string in Ada

Tags: ada, gnat

I have user input string which i am getting with `Get_Line`,
input from user can be like, each line terminated with new line,

```
1;2;3
4;50;6
7;A;8
1;;7
```

How can i parse each of this string one by one to get character, Integer and ';'?

--

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the subprograms in `Ada.Strings.Fixed`?  [This RM section](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-4-3.html) describes many subprograms that will be helpful.  I'm sure GNAT provides helpful functionality for string parsing also.  StackOverflow expects questioners to have done some research into their questions first.

Comment: @ajb: Thanks, for your answer. I am completely new to Ada, i can do this in C with ease, Just show me some pointers (some pseudo code) how can i do with Ada, that will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in Ada are arrays so getting a single character would be `Str(n)`

```
for i in Str'Range loop
  c := Str(i);
  ...
end loop;
```

and in Ada 2012 there are generalized `for` loops

```
for c of Str loop
  ...
end loop;
```

Comment: You don't have to copy `Str (I)` to `C` in the first version, to have a character, of course. -- This is exactly the basis for parsing a string (assuming that you know how to write a parser in the first place ;-).